# How to link Boost using CMake?

Tags: boost, cmake, clion

I installed Boost 1.60 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 using homebrew: `brew install boost@1.60`

I am running **CLion 2018.1.1** with my toolchain setup as follows: bundled **CMake 3.10.3**, C++ Compiler `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++` , GNU **Make 3.81**

my **CMakeLists.txt** file is as as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(xxx)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
Set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0)
find_package(Boost 1.60.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem regex)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
    include_directories(${BOOST_ROOT})
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Build seems to succeed:

`-- Boost version: 1.60.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   regex
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/include
-- Boost_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib
-- Boost_VERSION: 106000`

But I get the following **linker error** when I try to execute:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::perl_matcher(std::__1::__wrap_iter, std::__1::__wrap_iter, boost::match_results, std::__1::allocator > > >&, boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, std::__1::__wrap_iter) in main.cpp.o
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match()", referenced from:
>         bool boost::regex_match, std::__1::allocator > >, char, boost::regex_traits > >(std::__1::__wrap_iter, std::__1::__wrap_iter, boost::match_results, std::__1::allocator > > >&, boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags) in main.cpp.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this ?

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and post the link line. That will show the actual libraries you're trying to link against.

Comment: /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/language_features.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/language_features.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/language_features.dir/test/cpp_sorter_test.cpp.o  -o language_features -lgtest -lgtest_main /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.60/1.60.0/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib

Answer (score 0):

My bad: in my cross-build I was forcing **libc++** instead of **stdlibc++**

    `if (APPLE)
    #    add_definitions(-D__GLIBCXX__)`